# Radiusd server not serving the request

Tags: radius, freeradius, aaa-security-protocol

I have set up a radiud server on centos 6.8 and I have a switch that I want to call this radius server for authentication. The switch ip address is 10.2.1.4 which is there in the clients config file. Here is the part of my client conf file

```
client switch {
ipaddr = 10.2.1.4
secret = testing123
nastype = other
```

}

Below is the error that I am getting

```
 ... adding new socket proxy address * port 55146
Listening on authentication address * port 1812
Listening on accounting address * port 1813
Listening on command file /var/run/radiusd/radiusd.sock
Listening on authentication address 127.0.0.1 port 18120 as server inner-    
tunnel
Listening on proxy address * port 1814
Ready to process requests.
Ignoring request to authentication address * port 1812 from unknown client     
10.2.1.4 port 1037
Ready to process requests.
```

Can anyone please help me here?

Comment: You're editing the wrong clients.conf file or it's not being included.